# How to remove ↵ character from JS string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like

```
↵my name is Pankaj↵
```

I want to remove the `↵` character from the string.

```
"↵select * from eici limit 10".replace("↵", "")
```

Works fine. But I want to know if there is any other way to remove these kind of unnecessary characters.

Comment: One more info that "↵" character is not available in code editors like sublime-text or notepad++.

Comment: *way to remove these kind of unnecessary characters.* Do you wish to remove a set of characters like `↵`. If its just `↵` I would go for `replace`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using the literal character, you can use the codepoint.

Instead of `"↵"` you can use `"\u21b5"`.

To find the code, use `'<character>'.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)`, and then use like `\u<number>`.

Now, you can use it like this:

```
string.split("\u21b5").join(''); //split+join

string.replace(/\u21b5/g,'');  //RegExp with unicode point
```

Comment: This is a safe option instead of using ↵ directly, it will be converted into unsupported character which may not in all environments.

Answer (score 9):

> works fine.

If it works fine, then why bother? Your solution is totally acceptable.

> but I want to know is there is any other way to remove these kind of unnecessary characters.

You could also use

```
"↵select * from eici limit 10".split("↵").join("")
```

Comment: While extracting from the html element use **String.replace(/[\n\r]/g, '')** will solve this problem.

Comment: The above comment's regex worked for me, other solutions didn't.

Comment: @ArjunU. that means you're having actual line breaks in your string, not `↵` characters like the OP

Comment: *String.replace(/[\n\r]/g, '')* Solved my problem.

Comment: @ipankaj Can you please turn your comment into an answer? The others answers all seem inappropriate to handling this in JS.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try `regex` as well,

```
"↵select * from eici limit 10".replace(/↵/g, "")
```

Answer (score 1):

With something like

```
s.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ ]/g, "")
```

you can for example keep only alphabetic (`a-zA-Z`), numeric (`0-9`) underscores and spaces.

Some characters require to be specified with a backslash in front of them (for example `]`, `-`, `/` and the backslash itself).

You are however going to run into problems when your start deploying to an international audience, where "strange characters" are indeed the norm.

Comment: This answer points out too generic. OP is just asking how can he "replace" or remove a specific character, not how to use regex over a string. It can lead, as you clarify, to internationalization problems.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue but used the trim() function to clean out all extra spaces and ↵ characters.

```
str.trim();
```